# pandas retrieve values from one dataframe and do calculation on another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `df`,

```
df1
cur    dec_pl
JPY    2
HKD    1
GBP    0

df2
cur    amount
JPY    10
HKD    5
USD    100
GBP    10
```

I like to see if any `cur` of `df2` exists in `cur` of `df1`, and get the corresponding `dec_pl` values; for example, for `JPY` the `dec_pl` is 2, it means 10 to the power of 2, i.e. 10 * 10; multiplied it to its `amount` in `df2`, will get 1000; the result will be put in a new column `converted_amount`; if `cur` in `df2` cannot find a corresponding value in `cur` in df1 then its `converted_amount == amount`; so the result will look like,

```
cur    amount    converted_amount
JPY    10        1000
HKD    5         50
USD    100       100
GBP    10        10
```

I am wondering whats the best way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a `merge(join)` plus a conditional calculation, see code below,

```
df1 = pd.Series([2,1],index=['JPY','HKD'],name='dec_pl')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'amount':[10,5,100]}, pd.Index(['JPY','HKD','USD'],name='cur'))
```

Set up `df1` and `df2`, which are set up in this way to make join easier

**Method 1**

```
df2['converted_amount'] = (df2['amount']**df1).fillna(df2['amount'],downcast='infer')
```

You are able to do `df2['amount']**df1` even if they don't have the same shape. Pandas will try to align the index.

**Method 2**

(Left) join two datasets, and calculate power, if missing, default power is 1.

```
(df2.join(df1)
    .assign(converted_amount=lambda x:x.amount.pow(x.dec_pl.fillna(1,downcast='infer'))))
```

Output

```
cur amount  dec_pl  converted_amount
JPY 10       2.0    100
HKD 5        1.0    5
USD 100      NaN    100
```

I didn't drop `dec_pl`, to drop this, add `.drop('dec_pl',axis=1)` after that.

An interesting note is that if you're joining a series to a dataframe on indexes, you can actually use column assignment,

```
df2['dec_pl'] = df1
```

which works the same as `df2.join(df1)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first add a column `amount` that has `pow` of 10 for `dec_pl`. Perform a `right outer join` with `df1`. Then simply multiply the `amount` from both the dataframes with `.fillna(1)`. You have `res` that you want. Last step is to rename and drop unnecessary columns.

```
df1['amount'] = pd.Series([10]*len(df1)).pow(df1['dec_pl'])
res = df1.merge(df2, on='cur', how='right')
res['converted_amount'] = res['amount_x'].fillna(1).mul(res['amount_y'])
res = res.rename(columns={'amount_y': 'amount'}).drop(['dec_pl', 'amount_x'],1)
```

Output:

```
    cur amount  converted_amount
0   JPY 10      1000.0
1   HKD 5       50.0
2   USD 100     100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do a left join on df2 and df1, then replace `NaN` under dec_pl column with 0.
Here is the code to do that

```
df = pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left')
df['dec_pl'] = df['dec_pl'].fillna(0)
df['converted_amount'] = df['amount'] * 10 ** df['dec_pl']
df.drop(['dec_pl'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```